# Finding duplicates across multiple groups in a column- Python

Tags: python, group-by, duplicates

I need really serious help with some code.

I've a dataframe in which I want to find duplicates across 2 columns- Material Part Number & Manufacturer.The columns have null values. The way I need to find duplicates is as follows.

1. I first check the Part Number column for rows with no null values. As I do not want the null values to be treated as duplicates
2. If the part numbers match, for two same part numbers, I check the manufacturer column for duplicates.
3. Incase both the manufacturer and the part numbers are the same for two or more rows, I output result into a new column called level of duplicacy. The output is high for all the rows in which the part numbers and the manufacturers have an exact match.
4. However, if the part numbers match and the manufacturer doesn't match, the output into the column is 'Moderate'.
5. If the part number itself doesn't match, then Level of Duplicacy is 'No Duplicate'
6. Also, For rows which are NA in the part number or manufacturer, put the level of duplicacy as 'No Duplicate' incase of Part number and Moderate incase of Manufacturer.

This is my input table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGRY5.png)

The code I have written for the same is

```
`for i in range(len(df)):
    if pd.isnull(df.loc[i,'Material Part Number'])==False:
        if (df['Material Part Number'].duplicated(keep=False))[i]==True:
            if pd.isnull(df.loc[i,'Manufacturer'])==False:
                if (df['Manufacturer'].duplicated(keep=False))[i]==True:
                        df.loc[i,'Level of Duplicacy']='High'
                else:
                        df.loc[i,'Level of Duplicacy']='Moderate'
            else:
                 df.loc[i,'Level of Duplicacy']='Moderate'
        else:
            df.loc[i,'Level of Duplicacy']='Not duplicate'
    else:
         df.loc[i,'Level of Duplicacy']='Not duplicate'`
```

The output I need is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0wHj.png)

The output I'm getting is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91FF0.png)

As you can see in the rows highlighted in yellow, my code isn't comparing manufacturers within one particular/unique part number but it's doing it across all the part numbers and I don't want it to do that. I know that .duplicated() function compares for the entire column but what if I want it to compare within each unique part number and then find a match? More of a groupby with duplicated? Can one of you help me modify the code I have written?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Running a loop through the data frame would require you to do element wise comparisons of each item. I would suggest using matrix algebra to achieve this. Have a look below, this might be helpful.

```
df["Level of Duplicacy"] = "Not Duplicate"
Partdups = df.loc[df["Material Part Number"].duplicated(),"Material Part Number"].unique()
for dup in Partdups:
    Nums = df.loc[df["Material Part Number"] == dup,:]
    dupNums = Nums.loc[Nums["Manufacturer"].duplicated(),"Manufacturer"].unique()
    for num in dupNums:
        Nums.loc[Nums["Manufacturer"] == num,"Level of Duplicacy"] = "High"
        Nums.loc[Nums["Manufacturer"] != num,"Level of Duplicacy"] = "Moderate"
        df.iloc[Nums["Material Part Number"].index,:] = Nums

df.loc[pd.isnull(df["Material Part Number"]),"Level of Duplicacy"] = "Not Duplicate"
```

Comment: Hi, can you define stats? Throws an error. Also, the 'data' variable is the same as the initial data frame which is also 'df' in your function, right?

Comment: sorry about those mistakes, that was due to testing it on a different data-set on my side. Please have a look at the revised code and give it a swing again.

Comment: Hi, still throws an error as Status isn't defined. Can you tell me which variable does that indicate in my dataset?

Comment: Partdups is a list which contains the duplicated manufacturers numbers. the Nums lists contains all the material numbers which are duplicates. we then loop through the two lists. the column "status" refers to your material part number.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, Tried running it. But it treats NAs in the column as also duplicate and .duplicated gives True for NAs. I cant explicitly exclude the rows in which Manufacturer is NA. Because as I said if the part numbers match and manufacturer is NA, I still want the level of duplicacy to be moderate.Can you look at the algorithm that I require as mentioned in the question above and suggest changes to your code accordingly? I will re-run and let you know

Comment: you can add that last line after exiting the loop. the line of code was added to the original post. I really hope this will help.